# GCM Notification but how to display the message

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

i am completing android hive tutorial for GCM notification 
but now i am unable to display the message in next activity

Comment: post codes for notification

Comment: {"multicast_id":9043084625436315076,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":1,"results":[{"registration_id":"APA91bFFZDFvC8MSyL71eL-16YrU207GSzDS7dE6tavFaTawZnBsvdtgh9xCg_C5MKTN2Rd_bRSDkara_E4KSe1xIfzfYzHOsPcFHX8ty22RFfoxRUwEgibzKuQhevDI-Ltpv7JXac_FUCiit2S0LckmXqnL6Pvr-Q","message_id":"0:1438351195371703%978fee92f9fd7ecd"}]}                            i am getting the respose but not received any message from server

Answer (score 0):

The response you are getting as of now if from the GCM server with the `registration_id`. This registration_id should be saved to your third party server which will identify your app running on various Android devices when a push notification has to be sent.

Your server sends data in key/value pairs. Your app receives that data as key/value pairs in the extras in the Intent. You know what your keys are, so just retrieve the values out of the extras that are tied to those keys

(e.g., getStringExtra("message"), getStringExtra("url")).

You will be getting the data from your server through GCM in form of a payload that you need to parse.

```
String json = intent.getExtras().getString("payload");
```

After you parse all the data (test, icons) you can display in your respective activity of the android app.